# How can I stop an invited member on one board from viewing all other boards?

Tags: trello, permissions

I have invited a member to join a board relating to them but they can see all my other boards.

How can this be? & How can I stop it?

Answer (score 2):

By default the members of an organization can see all boards.

To hide a board from members mark it as Private (only invited members can then see it) from the Board Settings.